# Python: assign numpy array to a variable

Tags: python, numpy

I'm bit lost on one of the numpy statements to save data into two variables. In the below code, I see that while assigning the data "gre" and "gpa" to variable X, I see two square braces whereas while assigning values to variable  y , I notice only square braces. When I remove one of the square braces , I get a "key error" . Can someone explain the difference here? Tried online manuals but couldnt get my head around this.

```
data = pd.read_csv('student_data.csv')
X = np.array(data[["gre","gpa"]])
y = np.array(data["admit"])
```

Comment: this is not an issue with numpy. this is how dataframes work. data is a pandas dataframe (like a table structure) with column names "gre", "gpa" and "admit". You are trying to `select` two columns of the dataframe at once, so you pass the column names in a list, and use the list itself inside the data's square brackets as a form of selection. if you remove the square brackets, youre saying, select a column named `gre, gpa`, Which does not exist in the dataframe.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh thanks very much. That explains. I don't see an option to accept yours as an answer

Comment: No worries. I didn't feel like i deserved to write this as an answer, so i wrote it as a comment instead. If you wish, you can answer it yourself. If i turn the comment into the answer, i'd like to flesh it out more so it may help more people, but i do not have the time to do that right now.

Comment: I understand. Again, sincerely appreciate your time.